# Syncing two remote programs relying on time only (Python)

Tags: python, linux, networking, python-2.7, synchronization

**I have two programs, S and D,written in Python 2.7, running on seperate machines, both linux.**

The goal is to pass a file (in other words, bits) from S to D, through third party server called T only, without any contact between them, except the fact that I write S and D (and can plan any protocol that I want).

T is a simple echo server which is just sending back the message it receives.

The idea is to encode every bit to a number, and promote T's IP_ID field.
So if S wants to pass bit 1 to D, and let's say I encode 1 as +30 for the IP_ID value, then I'd send 30 empty packets to T just to increase it's IP_ID value by 30. D is sending packets to T once in a while to check if the IP_ID field increased, in order to decode the increment to the relevant bit, 1 or 0. So now D would see that the IP_ID was increased by 30, and it would write the bit 1, and so on.

And here comes my question:

**How can I sync / time S and D?**

I thought, for example, to write every 1 second from S to T.

Now, D knows that S is writing it's message every 1 second, so it would know to check the IP_ID value between those intervals.

**I can only use the module 'time' for the syncronization.**

I realized that letting S sleep 1 second and D sleep 1 second doesn't work, because S loop involving more operations than D, so after some time the timing will screw up and S will write to T when D is checking the value.

So I wrote my own function based on wall time, but it still doesn't work:

S code:

omitted

D code:

omitted

This syncronization doesn't work for some reason, and D is messing up with S (D reads while S writes to T).

Any ideas what's wrong with accurateSleep function? Maybe other method to check time?

p.s replaced "sleep" with a busyWait function instead, seems to be more accurate, but not enough.

Comment: Clocks will always drift unless they are synchronized eg. via NTP.

Comment: Try to use a logical clock with operation counters instead of a physical one. You always will run into problems with the synchronization of physical clocks.

Comment: @Jon, what do you mean? can you please show an example

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider implementing [I<sup>2</sup>C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) or [1-Wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire).  These may actually provide more capabilities than you need since they are both single master/multi slave bus systems and it sounds like you have exactly two devices.  If you don't mind the extra complexity they'll still get the job done, though.

I expect your equivalent of bringing a pin high or low would be either incrementing the shared counter or not incrementing it, respectively.

To address your clock desynchronization issues, you may also want to consider a using a [clock recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery) system such as [TMDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_Minimized_Differential_Signaling).  This is a well researched field since it is used by many modern video systems with extremely wide deployment.

Comment: Can I implement everything you suggested with the time module alone? Because it is the only module (except sys and socket) I could use.

Comment: No, sorry.  The buses are well documented on wikipedia and elsewhere.  If you have specific issues implementing them you should ask more questions.  "Can you show me how to implement X?" isn't a good question for stackoverflow.